# android ddms error

Tags: android, ddms

i'm getting this error when i run the ddms in android sdk tools:

[image]

From adb i change some settings from the Preferences > misc and i set the logging level as debbug.

[image]

and now i getting this:

[image]

Can you please help me to find out what the problem is?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be that the location of adb.exe has been moved from the tools directory to platform-tools. Try adding YourandroidSDK\platform-tools to your path.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. yes my adb is on platform-tools directory. What you mean by "Try adding YourandroidSDK\platform-tools to your path." thank you

Comment: If you are using Windows, then your Android SDK might be somewhere like "C:\dev\tools\android-sdk-windows" (That's where I put mine anyway, yours might be different) So using Control Panel, System, Advanced System Settings, Environment Variables - you can edit the PATH environment variable to include the platform-tools directory. I don't know how you do it in Linux though.

Comment: Just spotted this in the release notes fro SDK tools:             If you are upgrading to SDK Tools r8 from an earlier version, note that the the default installed location for the adb tool has changed from <SDK>/tools/adb to <SDK>/platform-tools/adb. This means that you should add the new location to your PATH and modify any custom build scripts to reference the new location. Copying the adb executable from the new location to the old is not recommended, since subsequent updates to the SDK Tools will delete the file.

Comment: yeah that's what happened i just upgraded to SDK Tools r8. I was trying to copy the adb.exe from new location to the old:P Thank you very much you help me a lot.